# Changing pan map symbol in QGIS 3.12

Tags: zoom, pan, qgis-3

I work with QGIS 3.12 and the default pan map symbol is

[image]

I try to find a way to change it into an arrow.

Comment: Do you want to change the hand icon of the button to an arrow icon? Or do you want to change hand cursor which appers after clicking the pan map button to an arrow cursor?

Comment: i want that when i pan in the map,the curser will be an arrow and not a hand